# How to prevent space before a column environment in beamer?

Tags: beamer, columns

I'm having the following block layout on one frame

```
\subsection{Typen}
\begin{frame}
 Zwei Arten von Typen
 \begin{block}{Wertetypen mit \texttt{rt::ValueType}}
   {
   \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded] % disable shadow
   \textit{Simple} oder \textit{Array}
   \begin{columns}
    \column[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Bei \textit{Simple}}
     Der genaue Typ
    \end{block}
    \column[t]{.45\textwidth}
    \begin{block}{Bei \textit{Array}}
     Anzahl an Elementen
    \end{block}
   \end{columns}
   \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[default] % enable again
   }
 \end{block}
\end{frame}
```

But it creates an ugly vertical space before the column environment. If I comment out the 4 column-environment specific commands, the vertical space is gone, which makes me think it's the column-environment's fault.

Is there a way to remove that vertical initial space?

Answer (score 7):

If you're after a local adjustment (i.e., only a few slides), can't you just add a `\vskip-5em` (or whatever space you want to remove) just after your `\begin{frame}`?

[image]

Otherwise, you can simply use `\begin{frame}[t]` (where `t` means top) to have your frame top-aligned. It can also be passed as a class option to align every frame.

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to put a two-column thing between two bullet points, so changing alignment won't help. I'll use the workaround, but this seems like a bug (at least, I'm seeing a *lot* of vertical space before the columns environment—about twice as much as appears after it, which doesn't seem like it'd be intentional).